# javascript compare arrays by values not by references

Tags: javascript, arrays, equals

I have to compare 2 such types  arrays in JS.

```js
var array1 = [

  null,
  "Marvel",
  "2.0.17",
  {
    name: "Hulk",
    color: "green",
    age: 31,
    abilities: ["crash", "smash"]
  },
  {
    name: "Iron Man",
    age: 35,
    stillAlive: true
  },
  ["Captain America", "Thor", "Captain Marvel"]
];


var array2 = [

  null,
  "Marvel",
  "2.0.17",
  {
    name: "Hulk",
    color: "green",
    age: 31,
    abilities: ["crash", "smash"]
  },
  {
    name: "Iron Man",
    age: 35,
    stillAlive: true
  },
  ["Captain America", "Thor", "Captain Marvel"]
];


function deepEquals(array1, array2) {
  //check if arguments are arrays
  if (!Array.isArray(array1) && !Array.isArray(array2)) {
    console.log("arguments are not arrays" + "\n")
    return false;
  }

  //check arrays by lenghts
  if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
    console.log("arrays lenghts are different" + "\n");
    return false;
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      if (typeof(array1[i]) !== "object" || typeof(array2[i]) !== "object" ||
        (array1[i] === null) || (array1[2] === null)) {

        //compare primitive values
        var primitiveCmp = comparePrimitives(array1[i], array2[i])
        if (primitiveCmp == false) {
          console.log("primitive values are different");
          return false;
        }
      } else {

        //compare pbjects
        var objCmp = compareObjects(array1[i], array2[i]);
        if (objCmp == false) {
          console.log("objects are different");
          return false;
        }

      }
    }

    console.log("arrays are equals" + "\n");
    return true;
  }
}


function comparePrimitives(var1, var2) {
  if (var1 !== var2) {
    console.log("primitive values are different: " + var1 + " and: " + var2 + "\n")
    return false;
  }

}

function compareObjects(o1, o2) {

  var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o1);
  var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o2);

  if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
    console.log("objects has diff count of property");
    return false;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
    var propName = aProps[i];

    // If values of same property are not equal,
    // objects are not equivalent
    if (o1[propName] !== o2[propName]) {
      console.log("objects are not equals they have different values of properties -> " +
        o1[propName] + " and-> " + o2[propName]);
      return false;
    }
  }

}



console.log(deepEquals(array1, array2));
```

When I call it I receive:

> objects are not equals they have different values of properties -> crash,smash and-> crash,smash
>   objects are different
>   false

How can I solve this problem? I need compare by values not by references.

Comment: Solve what problem, the arrays clearly aren't the same ?

Comment: second array same

Comment: var array2 = [

    null,
    "Marvel",
    "2.0.17",
    {
        name: "Hulk",
        color: "green",
        age: 31,
        abilities: ["crash", "smash"]
    },
    {
        name: "Iron Man",
        age: 35,
        stillAlive: true
    },
    ["Captain America", "Thor", "Captain Marvel"]
];

Comment: In the question, the second array contains `abilities: ["crash"]` instead of `abilities: ["crash", "smash"]`

Comment: When  function try to compare object which has array as property abilities: ["crash", "smash"] if thay same - it looks at links not at values

Comment: But the values clearly aren't the same, doesn't matter what you call it, it's still different ?

Comment: No it is mistake at ask. Arrays are the same. Answer is: objects are not equals they have different values of properties -> crash,smash and-> crash,smash
objects are different
false

Comment: Two arrays that contain the same values are not equal. You need to recurse into arrays and objects.

Comment: How to implement it

Comment: You need to check if type of `o1[propName]` and `o2[propName]` is array or not. If array call `deepEquals(o1[propName], o2[propName])` else check `o1[propName] !== o2[propName]`

Comment: ok, it is working. Thank you.

Comment: for your special objects ( same order), JSON.stringify(array1)===JSON.stringify(array2); would work too...

Comment: You have to sit and write a nested property comparison for objects types.